# How to link a samba file link in twiki?

Tags: samba, twiki

I've got a server using samba to share files.
Suppose the ip address is 1.1.1.1
so we can find the files in this samba server by using \1.1.1.1\
Now i've built a twiki system.I would like to make some links in the twiki topic to directly link to those files on the samba server but it seems [[\1.1.1.1\somefile]] failed to find the files.So how can I write those urls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the share or to access the share via an API like [pysmb](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb) in python. Although this is highly unlikely, if the language you're using knows about SMB protocol you can use that directly via a link.